# AngularJS doesn't display Cyrillic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, encoding, cyrillic

I have a problem with outputting Cyrillic in my AngularJS app, I've googled for this problem and there is no solution that suits me, the `bind-unsafe-html` is not what I'm looking for, I need to be able to bind data with angular expressions `{{like_so}}`. Is there a way?

Comment: Did you try anything? What is the exact problem? Does it display in a wrong way? Not at all? If you ask questions, please be as specific as possible, otherwise it will be very difficult for others to help you

Comment: So the thing is that when i try to output some cyrillic words in that way: set a string var in controller that has a word in cyrillic - display that var in angular app with expression {{var}}, so instead of the word i get - ������, i've tested this locally and angular works with cyrillic, i use meta charset = utf8 in both cases, could the problem be not in angular but the django?

Comment: try charset `windows 1251`

Comment: i've noticed something, when i add my javascript inside my html in <script> tag, everything works fine, but as soon as i connect that same script from remote file on my server this problem appears again, i can't possibly see the connection between having file remotely connected or having it inside html page

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i just messed up a file encoding in WebStorm, its was in windows-1251 and i just had to change it to utf-8